# AS3 Call a variable from a compound string

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, actionscript, switch-statement

I don't know how to explain this good, I'll do my best :p

I have this code:

```
public function clickeado(MouseEvent):void{

            if(getChildByName("placa") == null){
                addChild(info);
            }

            trace(MouseEvent.target.name)

            switch(MouseEvent.target.name){
                case "_783":
                    info.circuito_tf.text = _783_circuito;
                    info.localidad_tf.text = _783_localidad;
                    info.responsable_tf.text = _783_responsable;
                break;
```

I want that the text of "info.circuito_tf.text" to be the value of the variable called "_783_circuito". It's ok. Now I have 17 more cases, so I decided to do something like this:

```
switch(MouseEvent.target.name){
        case "_783":
            info.circuito_tf.text = MouseEvent.target.name + "_circuito";
            info.localidad_tf.text = MouseEvent.target.name + "_localidad";
            info.responsable_tf.text = MouseEvent.target.name + "_responsable";
        break;
```

I wish I explained well, thanks!

ps: the value of info.circuito_tf.text in the second case it's "783circuito" instead of the value of the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can address a variable through a string via this syntax:

```
info.circuito_tf.text = this[MouseEvent.target.name + "_circuito"];
```

Watch out for undefined values, though.

Yes, with this syntax you don't need the switch statement at all, just make sure your movie clips all have valid names and correct variables exist and are assigned values.